# CKEditor 4 image preview: programmatically setting dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4

I am adding plus / minus icon buttons to the CKEditor image properties preview for a user to click on them and increase / decrease the image width and height by a fixed number of pixels without having to type in the values.

I see that the keyup event updates the image preview as well as the lock ratio. How to correctly simulate the required keyup event in JavaScript / jQuery after the new pixel value has been set in the width / height input fields?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following works:

```
my_input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
                'key': '1'
              }));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).